# How to accept disabled software in System Information when button is not shown

Tags: audio, driver

I have recently upgraded my Macbook Pro to the M1 and during the time of me re-downloading and installing my applications that i use, i had ran into a problem. I had to install some audio drivers for my mixer. Now i had a couple issues accepting the software on my Macbook Pro Intel running Big Sur too, i had gone through much uninstalling and rebooting the machine as going into System Preferences > Security & Privacy and clicking allow on the software wasn't fixing my issue, the option wasn't even there. I then went into System Information after hours of researching and found the software in Disabled Software, there was a way for me to allow it. As soon as i allowed it, sound played through my mixer finally. But the issue is for some reason this Macbook does not have an option to accept it. It just shows me the driver is disabled but doesnt offer help on how to allow it. So here i am, il attach a screenshot of what it shows me here:

[image: disabled software]

I have no clue if its because this Macbook is an Apple Chip and not an Intel, it cannot be the Mac update Big Sur as the drivers work on my previous Mac. I really don't know and there's no source to tell me.

Is there a way i can allow this software?

Answer (score 1):

The chances are that you cannot just 'allow' Intel drivers on an Apple Silicon ARM Mac. It just won't work.

the Intel emulation/translation does not cover things like system extensions and input/output components.

You will need to go back to the manufacturers (Pioneer) and ask them for updated drivers. If the device is no longer supported, then you won't be able to use it with this Mac.